# Qualtrics: Embed data when option is selected

Tags: javascript

I need to design a decision problem where participants face several rounds and in each trail two options (lets call them option A and option B)
Option A will deliver a certain payoff (let’s say 10)
Option B will deliver an uncertain payoff (let’s say 100 with a probability of 20% otherwise 2).
After participants made their choice, they get feedback regarding their payoff in a subsequent screen. 
Also, participants are required to assess the probability of their previous choice. 
I spent days figuring out, how I could program this logic in JavaScript but I cannot figure it out. I hope someone here can help. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzE06.png)

Comment: Can you attach your attempt at the code?

Comment: Hello Jonathan, thank you for your reply!

Comment: Here is what I have got:
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var that = this;
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        if (element.type == 'left')  {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'certain', 10 );
 } else {
       Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'win gamble', 100 );
//here I would need wieghting logic to choose between winning and loosing with a certain probability
//Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'loose gamble', 2);"
        }
    }});

Comment: I basically have a multiple question with two items (left, right), and upon clicking on either button, a predefined payoff should be embedded. The problem with the above code is that the if (elment.type=="left") does not seem to work. Maybe I am using the work code at all. I have never programmed anything before.